# Using React to visualize algorithms - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, algorithm

I'm trying to create a website that visualizes popular algorithms - I'm using React (with Gatsby). I started with a bubble sort algorithm which is working, but there's something not quite right when I use react state and a `setTimeout` to update the view on each loop of the script. I can't work out exactly what the issue is but I'm wondering if it's something to do with the way state updates within the loop.

I know the function is working correctly because if I don't use a `setTimeout` then everything sorts perfectly (which is demonstrated by the Sort Array Instantly button). If I double click the Sort Array Visualize button then the sorting almost works - the bigger the delay between clicks the more buggy it is.

Here is a link to the site - https://determined-leakey-bd1b7d.netlify.com

Here is a link to the code - https://github.com/fishj123/algorithm-visualiser

Does anyone have any idea what the issue is?

Here is the code for the function that is being called:

```
let array = [...arr]
async function wait() {
return new Promise(function (resolve) {
setTimeout(resolve, 0);
});
}

for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
for(var j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {

if(array[i] > array[j]) {
await wait();
let temp = array[i];
array[i] = array[j]
array[j] = temp;
setArr(array);
}
}
}
```

Comment: Try pulling that function out of your component and passing in the function to set state as a param. I think it's probably because a new function is being created each render, which happens when you're setting state.

Answer (score 0):

To visualize on each iteration, I have added an `array` with numbers and changed the `setArr()` to have a `console.log()` in the code for replacing the representation of sorting from your solution which can be found below:

```js
(function() {
  async function sort() {
    // let array = [...arr] // original array
    let array = [4,5,6,34,3,23,324,23,345,34];

    function wait(ms) {
      return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
    }

    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      for(var j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
        if(array[i] > array[j]) {
          await wait(200);
          let temp = array[i];
          array[i] = array[j]
          array[j] = temp;

          //setArr(array); // removed from the example
          console.log(array); // added logging for representation
        }
      }
    }
  }
  
  sort();
})();
```

I hope this gives you the idea and helps. On each iteration after the given milliseconds (200ms) it logs the `array` to the console. I think you can use the same logic for the UI visualization what you are working on in your website.

**Additional update:**

Just for fun I was playing around with visual representation as well, please find it below:

```js
(function() {
  let array = [245,123,420,190,274,398];
  sort(array);      

  async function sort(array) {
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      for(var j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
        if(array[i] > array[j]) {
          await wait(200);
          let temp = array[i];
          array[i] = array[j]
          array[j] = temp;

          visualize(array);
        }
      }
    }

    function wait(ms) {
      return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
    }
    
    function visualize(array) {
      let sortChart = document.getElementById('sort-chart');
      sortChart.innerHTML = '';
      
      array.map(value => {
        let row = document.createElement('div');
        row.innerHTML = value;
        row.className = 'row';
        row.style.width = `${value}px`;
        sortChart.appendChild(row);
      });      
    }
  }
})();
```

```css
#sort-chart {
  border: solid;
}

.row {
  border: solid blue;
}
```

```html
<label>Visualization:</label>
<div id="sort-chart">
</div>
```

Not the nicest thing what I have made but it does what was intended to.

Comment: Thanks, whilst this solution does work (and is probably what I'll end up using) it doesn't answer the question of what the issue was with using React State. I guess it's just an async issue of some description.